# duplicated image in original gallery folder when having crop function

Tags: android, image, android-intent, crop

I am working on importing images from gallery, and discovered that

### with no crop function:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 10002);
```

### with crop function:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1024);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 800);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 1024);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 800);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
            intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
            intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true); // no face detection
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 10002);
```

### Question:

When there is no crop function, the final imageview can properly display the selected image.

When there is crop function, the final imageview can also properly display the selected image, but the folder from which the image is picked, now has a duplicated original image.

How could this duplicated image be removed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Android does not have a "crop function". Please use a library to crop images.

Comment: thanks a lot! I have searched and incorporated a library at https://github.com/edmodo/cropper